why can't I find "Add utility script" option in my Kaggle notebook?
I'm trying to use the "Add utility script" feature in my Kaggle notebook, but I can't seem to find the option. According to Kaggle's documentation and announcements, this feature should be available under the "File" menu. However, it's not appearing in my notebook interface.
I have checked extensively, including Kaggle's support discussions where the feature is mentioned as being launched (link to announcement: Import scripts into notebook kernels). I haven't found anyone else experiencing the same issue, which makes me wonder if there's a specific setting or step I might be missing.
Could someone please advise on how to enable or access the "Add utility script" option in Kaggle notebooks? It seems essential for organizing and reusing code efficiently, and I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this.
Thank you in advance for your help!

You need to go on the right panel, then select + Add Input. You'll have then the possibility to add utility scripts by selecting Utility scripts:

